# How to perform the multi-scale analysis beyond harmonic oscillations?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, non-linear-systems

I occasionally see this interesting method called [multi-scale analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-scale_analysis). From what I understood, it is used to perturbatively solve a perturbed harmonic oscillator, meaning that the equation of motion takes the form
$$(\partial_t^2+m^2)f(x)+\epsilon\,g[f(x)]=0,$$
where $g[f(x)]$ represents some general expression of $f(x)$ and $\epsilon$ indicates that this part is a perturbation, i.e., small compared with the first part.

The spirit is to introduce two time scales, one is related to $1/m$ and another is related to the perturbation and solve the equation of motion perturbatively in a way of avoiding secular terms.

I found this method very useful and tried to look for in some books its more general applications to. e.g., non-harmonic oscillators but did not find the information. For example, can we use this method to solve
$$(\partial_t^2+\lambda f(x)^2)f(x)+\epsilon\,g[f(x)]=0?$$
The non-perturbed motion would elliptical oscillations.

Any answer or recommendation of the references would be appreciated!